# Fill CGBitmapContext with color

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm trying to fill a CGBitmapContext with a solid red color and get CGImgRef, but image is all transparent.
Here's the code

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                             1,
                                             1,
                                             8,
                                             0,
                                             colorSpace,
                                             kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
CGFloat components[] = {1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0};
CGContextSetFillColor(context, components);
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1));
CGImageRef imgRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
```

Please don't recommend using UIBezierPaths and other UIKit things. I need to use CoreGraphics.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you forgot to set a fill color space. You *must* do that in order for `CGContextSetFillColor` to work correctly (because that tells it how many components to expect and how to interpret them). This works:

```
CGFloat components[] = {1,0,0,1};
CGContextSetFillColorSpace(context, colorSpace); // <-- this was missing
CGContextSetFillColor(context, components);
// and now fill ...
```

Comment: You were probably assuming that the color space of the context is the same as the context's current fill color space, but that's not true.

Answer (score -1):

problem was solved using `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor redColor].CGColor)`; Btw, it would be interesting to know what i was doing wrong. Also Apple documentation on CGContextSetFillColor says "Note that the preferred API to use is now CGContextSetFillColorWithColor."

Comment: Even simpler: `[[UIColor redColor] set];`. No need for`CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`.

Comment: @rmaddy but he stipulated no UIKit. A stipulation which his answer then violates, of course...

Comment: @matt Well look at that. My comment was based solely on what I saw in the answer. I don't read the whole question.